# PHP Array of Objects with reference

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, object

I know how to do this in javascript using the following code

```
var objectArray = [];
var cnt         = 0;

while(cnt < 5) {
    objectArray[cnt] = {};
    objectArray[cnt]['field01'] = cnt;
    objectArray[cnt]['field02'] = "Nothing";
    cnt++;
}
```

which I can then reference using

```
console.log(objectArray[2]['field01']);
```

for example

Is there an equivalent way to do this in php without using a class?

Comment: yes that was a typo, thanks

Comment: use StdClass if you want an empty object, but I suggest you simply use an array. Arrays in PHP, unlike in javascript, can hold arbitrary scalar values (while remaining to be ordered).

Comment: No special *thing* required in php as php arrays are always hash-maps and thus can take numeric and string indices.

Comment: What specifically makes you think you need a class? What about "this" is so special?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax is very similar to Javascript and you don't need to use objects.

```
$array = []; // Will work PHP 5.4+, otherwise use array();
$cnt = 0;

while($cnt < 5) {
    $array[$cnt]['field01'] = $cnt;
    $array[$cnt]['field02'] = 'Nothing';
    cnt++;
}
```

or...

```
$array = [];

for( $cnt=0; $cnt<5; $cnt++ ) {
    $array[$cnt]['field01'] = $cnt;
    $array[$cnt]['field02'] = 'Nothing';
}
```

Edit:
A bit of a mashup, there's no need to manually define the index of your array if it's starting from 0 and incrementing.

```
$array = [];

for( $cnt=0; $cnt<5; $cnt++ ) {
    $array[] = [
        'field01' => $cnt,
        'field02' => 'Nothing'
    ];
}
```

Comment: which method would you recommend using, this one you suggested or the one that @patrick suggested because both seem to work

Answer (score 2):

This PHP code would do the same as your script:

```
$objectArray = array();
$cnt = 0;

while($cnt < 5){
    $objectArray[$cnt] = array(
        'field01'   => $cnt,
        'field02'   => 'Nothing'
    );
    $cnt++;
}

echo $objectArray[2]['field01'];
```